# jquery clone form fields while i clone the (first) form value is not to retrieval again..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

used the the clone and appendTo method but while i clone the same value is come again it get the value from the first form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#clone").on("click", function(){
$("#forms").clone().appendTo("body");
});
```

Comment: Cloning means copying and ofcourse it will have the same copy when you append to body! What's the problem here??

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: while i clone an form the same form is  came again but the value i entered in the first form is not remove in the cloned form or second form.(the cloned form is to be an fresh form not the same value is taken from the first)

Comment: naturally. If you clone a "pre-filled" form, your data is cloned too. Problem is also that your form inputs have attributes called "name" that are... kinda "useful" you know...